# Error:(18, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: java, android

i'am new on android application, i imported an application and i get this error dont know what to do.. someone here can help me! 
there is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
 allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
        }
        }

     android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
          buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
                }
```

and there is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codeandcoder.finalguide"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
   }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
      }
       }

     dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly !

Comment: Hi @ilham, I was looking other post. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Move this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

to `module/build.gradle`

Comment: i have already android and dependencies in my module/build.gradle

Comment: You have to use them just in `module/build.gradle`, not in your project gradle

Comment: i got this error when i delete them from project gradle : Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.